# OOP: Is it going to far to create a phone number object, or an address object?

Tags: oop, object

Many things can have phone numbers and addresses. . . people, places, etc. You want phone numbers and addresses to have the same functionality, format and validation whether it is a phone number or address for a person or a place etc.

Is it going to far to create a phone number class, and an address class, and use them in those objects that have phone numbers and addresses?

My question goes to other properties as well that could be reuseable across diverse objects.

Comment: I think the answer would depend on the context, but without a context, it seems a bit pointless .. DDD (Domain Driven Design) is always a good way to go.

Comment: Well that's where I'm getting at here. In a complex domain model, you will have some properties (phone number, address), that have the same format, validation, functionality, etc., wherever they are. But they are more complex than something simple like say a gender, or an age, or a birthdate. So . . . should they have their own class?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you *can* go too far and this is borderline. I tend to draw the line at the point where it becomes cumbersome to treat things as more than a string, or another already defined class/type.

If you need to somehow *manipulate* phone numbers (by, for example, separating them into area code and other bits) or addresses (number, street, city, country and so forth) then, yes, consider making them objects.

I rarely do anything with phone numbers or addresses other than store and display them, in which case they're fine as strings without having to have their own dedicated class. For addresses, I don't even impose a separation based on parts (except maybe the zipcode), preferring free-format entry so as to not annoy those with addresses of a format I don't know about.

Going the reductio ad absurdum route, you could also objectify the characters that make up your phone number but that would be silly.

Comment: +1 for depends on context. If I am a telephone carrier, even the area code is going to be modeled as its own class. If I am a post office, even the zip code will have its own class, or maybe even more fine-grained than that.

Comment: I love that you say it's borderline. That's why I threw it out there. LOL
@Anurag: I agree, definitely contect. But even in a vanilla business domain, do I really want to rewrite phone number code over and over. And same for address. In my case I always break out the address so I don't get garbage data, and I don't really want to rewrite that over and over again either. Even if it's just from project to project, and not necessarily multiple times within the same project. Thanks both of you.

Comment: but, but, you mean my `class Five extends ArabicNumeral` and my `class ArabicNumeral extends NumericLikeObject` are not necessary?!? ;-)

Comment: @Andrew: I don't know. If you need methods to treat `Five` differently to, say, `Three` then, yes, subclass `ArabicNumeral` for it (I did get the humor, BTW, but it was an interesting enough question for a real answer as well).

Answer (score 4):

I think it would be perfectly acceptable. A well designed class will allow you to reuse it in many different projects. If you have many projects that could use this sort of functionality, using an object is the perfect way to ensure that your code is reusable and portable. The extensibility and the potential for you to extend the functionality of your class to handle anything phone number/address related would be unmatched by a set of functions or once off code you rewrite over and over.

In the end it's your call, personally I think it would fall under good practice though.

Answer (score 1):

You need an `Entity Class` and `Address Class`.

`Entity` can be person, place, organisation, coffee shop kinda, whereas `Address` can capture  Phone number, emailid, Lat/Long kinda stuff.

Keeping Entity and Address will help you across diverse objects.
and having many to many relation ship among entity and address would help, having loose coupling wud help on long run.